# Box Windows SDK missing many API calls?

Tags: c#, box-api

I'm working on a WPF application utilizing the Box Windows SDK.  I'm looking to use the GetUsers API method (authenticating as an admin user) to get all the enterprise users in our organization and then On-behalf-of calls in order to list the folders and files for particular users (my API key has already been granted on-behalf-of access).  It seems like none of this functionality is currently available in the Windows SDK.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that is correct.  The Windows SDK supports most of the non-administrative API calls at the moment.

All the SDKs are open-source, so you can contribute if you want.   The pattern is fairly simple to add another header.  Or to add an additional noun

Note that you should use as-user instead of on-behalf-of.